# Hue and Saturation range in openCV seems conflicting

Tags: opencv

As far as i know, the hue and saturation range are 0 to 180 and 0 to 255 for hue and saturation respectively.

But in histogram comparison exmaple in [**openCV docs**](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/histogram_comparison/histogram_comparison.html), they have taken the following:

```
  // hue varies from 0 to 256, saturation from 0 to 180
  float h_ranges[] = { 0, 256 };
  float s_ranges[] = { 0, 180 };
```

Shouldn't it be the reversed case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you're right. it's a bug.

```
// hue varies from 0 to 180, saturation from 0 to 256
  float h_ranges[] = { 0, 180 };
  float s_ranges[] = { 0, 256 };
```

(the sample in cpp/tutorials does the right thing actually)

[edit] [will be fixed soon.](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/pull/2460)